# Snmpd blind scan on different subnet

Tags: networking, snmp, snmpwalk

I have `snnpd` installed on 3 computers on the same subnet and can discover the rest from any computers in that network.

The command I use is: `snmpwalk -v 1 public ip`

However, when I move one to different subnet, it disappears from the query result. Are there any options for me to blind scan that computer or I must provide network info of this one to `snmpwalk`?

Comment: Have you verified that snmpd is listening on the new IP address when you assign it a new IP address for the other subnet, e.g., with a `netstat -an | grep 161` command if it is a LInux or OS X host. If it is Windows system, you can substitute `find "161"` for the grep command. Is the system you are querying, when it is on the new subnet, accessible from the system from which you are issuing the snmpwalk command, e.g., can you ping it or otherwise access it?

Comment: I can ping the transferred machine and port 161 is open